# Failed to create table with @Query in Room database

Tags: android, database, android-studio, android-sqlite, android-room

My @Dao interface is:

```java
@Dao
public interface TaskDao {
    @Insert
    void insert(Task task);

    @Update
    void update(Task task);

    @Delete
    void delete(Task task);

    @Query("DELETE FROM task_table")
    void deleteAllTasks();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM task_table")
    LiveData<List<Task>> getAllMainTasks();
}
```

Using this query every thing works fine and just as wanted. Here is the table screenshot:
[image]

Changing the last two lines to below lines causing problem:

```java
    @Query("SELECT * FROM task_table WHERE creator_ID = NULL ORDER BY task_ID ASC")
    LiveData<List<Task>> getAllMainTasks();
```

But when I use this, no entry in this table is created!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace your null-condition:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM task_table WHERE creator_ID = NULL ORDER BY task_ID ASC")
```

to

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM task_table WHERE creator_ID is NULL ORDER BY task_ID ASC")
```

Comment: Problem fixed. But when should I use `IS` and when `=`? Is there any difference between `is`(what you used here) and `IS`(as everything in @Query is in upper letter)?

Comment: To compare value with null in query - use "someField is null" or "someField is not null", no "= null". As for "upper letter" what is the source of your information? It's case insensitive, at least technically. May be there is some code style written, I never seen it.

Comment: Oh sorry! I've seen use of upper letter in every example. So I thought it's also case sensitive like Java(I apologize). Thanks for your help.